# Python3.6 |- Check if string is True or False -|

Tags: python, if-statement, terminal, console, python-3.6

## Hello!

I wanna check if user typed string is True or False, my program creates a new variable when the user type `data.create {name} {value}` and this variable is stored in a list called "data", with some script it gets the name and the value and can print using `type $data.{name}`.

To not make any problems or make the program more hard, it formats the string, so think that I created a data: `data.create hllw Hello World` and then I typed it on the console: `type $data.hllw`, the first thing that is executed is the formater because if it detect an `$data` in the string, it separates by a dot and get the name and check if the variable exists on the list. So `type $data.hllw` turns into `type Hello World`

Now, I want to make an `if` command, that do this: `if $data.hllw == Hello World` (If hllw var is "Hello World" it return True, else return False), but I don't know do this, I thinked that eval() can help, but no: `if eval(args):` (args = the arguments of if).

If I try:

```
if args:
    print('True!')
else:
    print('False!')
```

it returns always "True!" :(

#### Anyone that can help? I will be happy ;)

Comment: If you just `print(args)`, what's there? What you're testing with `if args` is just that it's something truthy. `None`, `False`, numeric zero, and empty strings and collections are falsey, but everything else is truthy—the string `"False"`, the number `-1`, etc.

Comment: when I print the args it says: "$data.hllw == Hello World"(Without the formater), "Hello World == Hello World"(With the formater)

Comment: OK, so that's obviously a non-empty string, and therefore truthy. That's why your code prints `True!`.

Comment: Also: You've got expressions in some other language that isn't Python (`$data.hllw` is not a valid Python identifier, and `Hello World` without quotes around it is not a valid Python string), so I'm not sure why you think `eval` will help. You need to interpret it as… whatever language that is.

Comment: Hum, How can I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to write a parser and interpreter for a custom language you invented. That's a non-trivial project, and not something someone can cover in a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: It's not a programming language, it's a terminal, like on windows cmd we can type `if "text" == "text" echo It's a text!`

Comment: It's definitely not a terminal, or a terminal emulator. And if it has expressions like `if <something> == <something>`, then it's a programming language.

Comment: But on windows cmd we can type an if

Comment: And that isn't a programming language... probably

Comment: Yes, it is very definitely a programming language (albeit not a very good one), and `cmd` is (among other things) an interpreter for that language.

Comment: Oh, ok... Thx for the help(If I can call that help, but, what can I make?). Have a good day

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you want to build a python-backed shell which has it's own custom commands. I think you're looking for `eval(f"'{hllw}' == 'Hello World'")`, but you shouldn't use python's `eval` for evaluating user-input because that's a big security hole. Better implement your custom shell-commands by defining functions and let your read-eval-print loop (REPL) call these after parsing.

Comment: @Darkonaut Evaluating user input is only a security hole if there is something Python can do that you want to prevent the user from doing. But if the plan is to create a shell, presumably you want that shell to be able to launch python, and then the user can do everything Python can do. So I see no big security problem here, personally.

Comment: @DanielWagner Probably I didn't mean a real shell but a limited REPL for a small app. But yeah, if you start it already from a real shell, you already have the access, so warning against `eval()` for this use case doesn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 0):

The only scenario where your `if` statement will return `False` is when you test a empty string. You do not need a special function.